# Efficiently collect links in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe of type

```
individual,  location, food
         1          A     a
         1          A     b
         1          B     a
         1          A     c
         2          C     a
         2          C     b
```

where individuals are creating links between location and food. I would like to collect all links on the individual basis. That is, if an individual was observed at locations `A` and `B` and had (eventually) food at `a`, `b`, and `c`, I want to link *all* these locations and food types against each other:

```
    location   food
           A      a
           A      b
           A      c
           B      a
           B      b
           B      c
           C      a
           C      b
```

One - extremely inefficient - way of doing so is

```
import itertools
def foo(group):
    list1 = group.location.unique()
    list2 = group.food.unique()
    return pd.DataFrame(data=list(itertools.product(list1, list2)), columns=['location', 'food'])
df.groupby(df.individual).apply(foo)
```

Is there any better way to get this done?

Answer (score 2):

You can pick up some efficiency by using numpy's `meshgrid`.

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
def foo(group):
    list1 = group.location.unique()
    list2 = group.food.unique()
    return pd.DataFrame(data=list(itertools.product(list1, list2)), columns=['location', 'food'])

def bar(group):
    list1 = group.location.unique()
    list2 = group.food.unique()
    product = np.meshgrid(list1, list2)
    # reversing the order is necessary to get the same output as foo
    list3 = np.dstack([product[1], product[0]]).reshape(-1, 2)
    return pd.DataFrame(data=list3, columns=['location', 'food'])
```

On my machine there was a small, (~20 %) speedup

```
In [66]: %timeit df.groupby(df.individual).apply(foo)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.57 ms per loop

In [67]: %timeit df.groupby(df.individual).apply(bar)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.16 ms per loop
```